# Find the perimeter of the leaf

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, canny-operator

Here is a leaf

[image]

I want to find the length of it's periphery i.e. it's perimeter using openCV and Python.I tried writing a code but it is not giving the desired result.I have to reset the threshold for every example and also it's not giving a closed contour.I want it to be a generalized code to work on all such leaves. Please help me here:

```
import cv2
#reading the image 
 col = cv2.imread("leaf2.jpg")
 width,height,channels = col.shape
 col=cv2.resize(col,(width,height),interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
 image=cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(col,10,100,3)

 edged = cv2.Canny(image, 0,10)
 kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
 closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
 #finding_contours 
 image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

 perimeter=0

 for c in contours:
     peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
     approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
     cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
     perimeter = perimeter+cv2.arcLength(c,True)
 print(perimeter)   
 cv2.imshow("Output", image)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: "it isn't very successful" is not a very useful problem statement - please be more specific.

Comment: Done. Now can you help me fix the code?

Comment: Is the background always that same colour/texture? If not, please provide additional examples. Are the leaves always green, or could they be reddish or other colours? Can there be multiple leaves in one image? Overlapping or not?

Comment: Yes. The background is always the same colour and texture. Also, leaves are always in shades of green. And there is no overlapping, there's always single leaf in an image.

Comment: How about instead you calculate the bounding box of the leaf and then calculate the diagonal length? This should roughly match the length of its periphery.

Comment: How can I find the bounding box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HSV color space is ideal for this image because the color difference between the leaf and the background is extreme. The Hue layer of HSV is only concerned with color and not the intensity of light so we use it here.

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv = cv2.split(hsv)
gray = hsv[0]

gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), sigmaX=-1, sigmaY=-1)

ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

contours = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (255,0,0), thickness = 2)
```

[image: binary] [image: result]

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect :)